# how to find out all the checked out files in a branch

Tags: clearcase

As title, could anyone of you  give me a working instruction to solve that problem ?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only after checked-out *files* and you are in a dynamic view set to see only MY_BRANCH:

```
ct lsprivate -co .
```

(with '.' being the parent directory under which you want to find co files)
That command is recursive by default.
Your config spec would need to be

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../MY_BRANCH/LATEST
element -directory /main/LATEST
```

With checked-out files *and directories* in a snapshot or dynamic view, use indeed lsco, but knowing that command is *not* recursive by default. So I would recommend:

```
ct lsco -rec -brtype MY_BRANCH
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ct lsco -brtype your-branch-type-selector
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by having a look here : [IBM ClearCase Command Reference : lscheckout](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscheckout.htm)

Then, as an example, try this...

If your branch was foo, and your are in the VOB you want to check, you can run

```
  ct lsco -brtype foo
```

or

```
  ct lsco -brtype brtype:foo
```