# RTC source control displaying a pending change when no change has been made

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Within 'Pending Changes' RTC source control is listing my target folder as an outgoing change. My project is maven based. I have not made any changes to the target folder.

[image]

When I compare the target folder with the stream I am flowing to I there are no differences displayed :

[image]

Is there some other criteria that is causing the 'Pending Changes' view to list my target folder & how can I determine what change is being recognized by RTC ?

When I try and undo the changeset within the target folder I receive the error :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The little `+` in the black arrow above the '`target`' directory means RTC detects said directory as a *new* element to be delivered.
That means you must have checked in that directory with the rest of your changes.

Generally, `target` should be ignored (ie never considered to be checked-in in the first place).
In your case, you should:

- remove that directory from your [changeset](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/c_csets.html&re=1&scope=null) (assuming you didn't already complete the changeset): <del>try `undo` on the target directory within your changeset</del>.
  (That would actually trigger, for a newly created element, the error message
  "`Undoing this change would produce an orphan with no parent folder`").
  **Right-click and select "`ignore`"**
  (don't select "`Reverse`" on the changeset itself: it would roll back all the changes currently checked-in)
- add it to your `.jazzignore`: the ignore option will add or create a `.jazzignore`, in order to declare your directory in it.

Of edit your `.jazzignore` if you have already one, with a content like:

```
core.ignore.recursive= \
    {target}
```

---

Note: with ClearCase, the issue is different, since ClearCase doesn't detected what is private from what is checked-out (and you don't check out with RTC).
You need to ask explicitly for [all private files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657084/command-to-find-all-view-private-files-in-the-current-directory-recursively/7657120#7657120) or [all checked out files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576701/how-to-find-out-all-the-checked-out-files-in-a-branch/1577552#1577552).

Comment: when I try and undo the changset I receive error. Ive added it to original question.

Comment: @user470184: in that case, an easier solution would be to select `ignore` instead of undo, which should directly register that element to a `.jazzignore` file

Comment: another option which ive just tried is to 'discard' the changeset, although ive just discovered this rolls back file changes so not so useful if lots of changes have been made.

Comment: Yes, ive tried ignore and it removes the ignored folder from the 'Pending Changes' view, although I think I tried this before and it did not, I can't be sure. Thank you.

Comment: @user470184: you are Welcome. I had carefully avoided the "`Discard`" option because I knew it would actually roll back changes. I have edited the answer to include that caveat.